# Interest in a group-watching of Star Trek:TOS?

Tags: discussion

This year is the 45th Anniversary of *Star Trek: The Original Series*.  As a sort of celebration, I was wondering if there was interest in doing a sort of <strike>book</strike> TV club where we watch a few episodes and discuss in chat.  Depending on people's availability, we could do a simultaneous viewing with people in chat having a conversation about the episode we're all watching.  I'd also highly recommend posting questions people have as they watch.

For people in the US (and maybe Canada?), *Star Trek* is easy to watch, as Netflix Streaming has the entire series available.

Answer (score 6):

I love this idea. What we should do is have 4-5 episodes in a batch, do a batch a week, and at the start of the batch we run a chat event where people can watch together. And then for the rest of the week people are encouraged to watch up and answer questions.

Would also be a great way to use the blog more, as we can list the weekly episodes and whatever other details we want.

I think this would be great to do as more than just ST:TOS, also. Maybe the first batch or few is TOS, and then we branch out into other shows and maybe movies too.

Great idea. Kudos Keen.